# Block colors in react react-native-linear-gradient?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, linear-gradients

Is it possible to get colors in blocks when using react-native-linear-gradient ? Everything I've tried gives a fade between the colors.

Desired effect

[image]

The code below still gives a faded effect. I don't really know how the x,y co-ordinated work.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
 <LinearGradient 
   start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
   locations={[0.6, 0.8, 1]} colors={['orange', 'brown', 'yellow']}
  >
   <--COMPONENT-->
  </LinearGradient>
</View>
```

Comment: can you share some code, please

Comment: you can use view as a box and flexdirection row

Comment: @Noni I've added the code now.

Comment: @MayankPandav flexdirection row did not work. I put that on the view tag.

Answer (score 0):

i have created sample demo on box with flexdirection hope you clear with it example Link:
[demo of boxcolor](https://snack.expo.io/@immynk/block_demo)